# Calling async function inside a loop

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I have the following function:

```
function ipfsRetrieve( ipfsHash ){
  return new Promise( function( resolve, reject ) {
    ipfs.catJSON( ipfsHash, (err, result) => {
        if (err){                
            reject(err);
        }
        resolve( result);           
    });
});
```

}

Now, when I call this function inside a loop as below:

```
var hashArray   = [ "QmTgsbm...nqswTvS7Db",
                "QmR6Eum...uZuUckegjt",
                "QmdG1F8...znnuNJDAsd6",                    
              ]

var dataArray   = []; 
hashArry.forEach(function(hash){
    ipfsRetrieve( hash ).then(function(data){
        dataArray.push(data);
    });
});  

return dataArray
```

The "return dataArray' line returns an empty array. How should I change this code to have the "dataArray" filled with the data retrived from IPFS?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: The question is about dealing with multiple async requests in a loop.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using async/await with a forEach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `Promise.all`.

Construct an Array of Promises and then use the method to wait for all promises to fulfill, after that you can use the array in the correct order:

```js
let hashArray = ["QmTgsbm...nqswTvS7Db",
  "QmR6Eum...uZuUckegjt",
  "QmdG1F8...znnuNJDAsd6",
]

// construct Array of promises
let hashes = hashArray.map(hash => ipfsRetrieve(hash));

Promise.all(hashes).then(dataArray => {
  // work with the data
  console.log(dataArray) 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

For starters, you need to return after rejecting, or else your resolve will get called too.

```
function ipfsRetrieve( ipfsHash ){
  return new Promise( function( resolve, reject ) {
    ipfs.catJSON( ipfsHash, (err, result) => {
        if (err){                
           reject(err);
           return;
        }
        resolve( result);           
    });
});
```

Now for the loop, use map instead of forEach, and return the promise.
Then wait on the promises.

```
let promises = hashArry.map(hash=> return new Promise(resolve,reject) { // your code here handling hash, updating theData, and then resolving })
return Promise.all(promises).then( ()=> return theData)
```

In your case, the promise is provided by ipfsRetrieve, so you would call

```
let promises = hashArry.map(ipfsRetrieve)
return Promise.all(promises)
```

The caller of your functions will do this:

```
ipfsRetrieve().then(data=>{ // process data here } )
```

If you are cool with async await, do this. (marking containing function as async)

```
let data = await ipfsRetrieve()
```

Comment: "*code here updating theData and then resolving*" - no no no. Call `ipfsRetrieve`  and use `then`, don't use `new Promise`

Comment: I think it's pretty clear what the OP wanted to achieve with `ipfsRetrieve( hash ).then(function(data){
        dataArray.push(data);
    })`. When using `Promise.all` properly, you don't need any "data updating" at all.

Comment: Someone is going to want the data when the promises all resolve.

Comment: Yes, and that's what `Promise.all` does for you

Comment: The original function returns a data array.  You can't do that, you have to return a promise and resolve it.  This is getting silly.

Comment: `return Promise.all(hashArray.map(ipfsRetrieve));` is all that is necessary. No need to introduce and fill some explicit `dataArray`.

Comment: Yes that's true, Promise.all returns an array of the resolved values.